# Resizing елемента в левую сторону

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

Реализовал `resize` елемента в право таким образом.

```
function resize() {
    $('.sossage')
        .mousedown(function (e) {
            offsetx = e.offsetX;
            var elWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
            if (e.offsetX >= elWidth - 5 && e.offsetX <= elWidth) {
                my_target = e.target;
                resizeState = true;
                clientXforResize = e.clientX;
                initialWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
                disable = true;
                drag();
            }
        })
        .mouseup(function (e) {
            resizeState = false;
            var elWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
            if (e.offsetX >= elWidth - 5 && e.offsetX <= elWidth) {
                resizeState = false;
                my_target = null;
                disable = false;
                drag();
            }
        });

    $(document)
        .mousemove(function (e) {
            if (resizeState == true) {
                var widthOffset = clientXforResize - e.clientX;
                $(my_target).css({
                    'width': (initialWidth - widthOffset) + 'px'
                });
            }
        })
        .mouseup(function () {
            resizeState = false;
        });
}
```

При попытке сделать `resize` в лево по такому же принципу столкнулся с проблемой - при увеличении ширины елемента увеличение все равно происходит в правую сторону.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Увеличение и должно так происходить. Всегда вниз и вправо, потому что браузер только так может быть уверен, что все подвинет, начало кординат же сверху слева.

Решением Вашей проблемы будет таким. В тот момент, когда вы растягиваете свой объект влево, кроме увеличения ширины добавьте ещё и отрицательный margin на измененную длину: `marginLeft = -(initialWidth - widthOffset)`.

Comment: Работает, но с нюансом. Если увеличивать влево, а потом в право, т при следующем изменении ширины влево елемент `скачет`

Comment: @Baga, покажите Ваш код.

Comment: codepen.io/anon/pen/JYOPQE